# Postfix can send to everywhere except Comcast?

Tags: email, postfix

I have a VPS running CentOS that hosts a few websites with email.  It's recently come to my attention that outgoing emails to @comcast.net addresses are not delivering.  I've observed that these emails are stuck in the queue for days before bouncing, so it's not a temporary outage.

-I confirmed the bounces happening to multiple @comcast.net addresses, not just one

-I confirmed that I can send to these same addresses successfully from other email address not hosted on this VPS

-I confirmed the bounces happening FROM multiple emails on multiple domains on this VPS.  Originator doesn't seem to matter

So it just seems like this VPS can't send to Comcast.  These are the type of errors that come back from Postfix.    Does this message mean anything in particular?   Any ideas of possible causes?

connect to mx2c1.comcast.net[2001:558:fd00:4f::5]:25: Network is unreachable

connect to mx1a1.comcast.net[2001:558:fd01:2bad::5]:25: Network is unreachable

edit:  output of the command 'ip -6 addr show'

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::c420:cbff:fe3a:fc09/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: What is the value of `inet_protocols` in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` ? And did you configure ipv6 interfaces (`ip -6 addr show`) ?

Comment: my inet_protocols is set to 'all'.   I'll edit the question with the content of 'ip -6 addr show'

Comment: The IP6 address begining `fe80::` is [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses) and cannot be used for making connections on the Internet. Either get a 'scope global' IP6 address assigned to your VPS (by your ISP or hoster), or tell postfix to use IP4 (but only if other MXes you want to reach also support IP4, otherwise you'll get an equivalent problem with them).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 is spot on. You cannot use that type of ip6 addresses in a global context. Contact your provider  for an assigned ip6 address range, and assign that to the ethernet interface and postfix config. For the time being, you may add a config entry http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps to postfix main.cf, and create a transport map file holding just one entry for comcast to an ip4 MX. If you need further help, just ask.

Comment: Thanks gerhard and dave for your comments, helping me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request from the IP or IP range may be dropped by their firewall - assuming that these MX are up and running.
Just try to reach them from the shell of the VM and your localhost - if only one of them can reach these, it is save to assume that.

Comment: Do you mean to ping them?  I haven't got any response from pinging them, doing it from the VM and also from elsewhere.

Comment: Simply using IPv4 seems like the most practical thing to do for right now.  (and yes, once I did this, emails went through to Comcast no problem).   Thanks so much.

Comment: Surely, this works for the moment. It is no solution for the future, though.

Comment: @gerhardd. That's not the case, because an already registered IP4 doesn't care about other IP addresses. And it definitely is the ultimate solution, unless Comcast would fix their IPv6 mappings. https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3acomcast.net&run=toolpage ...as one can see, it's known to DNS, but their mail-servers don't respond to it.

Comment: IPv4 is just a subset of IPv6 ...and that's is why this is future proof.

Comment: ... until there are no MX with ip4 anymore. ;-) Btw: Ip6 is a totally different protocol than ip4. The problem with not responding ip6 MXers is currently existing for comcast only. One needs to fix his ip6 config in any case.